# Пунктуация в сложноподчиненном предложении (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

***Он не видел ни того, кто это сделал, ни того, чем было совершено это преступление.***

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли написано предложение?

Comment: Интересно, а какая именно запятая вызывает сомнения?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, какая именно запятая Вас интересует. Знаки расставлены правильно.

Главное предложение — *Он не видел ни того(1), ни того(2).*
(1) —  указательное слово **тот** (в падеже); (2) — указательное слово **то** (в падеже).

Придаточные предложения —  *кто это сделал; чем было совершено это преступление.*

Придаточные предложения отделяются от главного запятыми. Если придаточное предложение стоит в середине главного, то придаточное предложение отделяется от главного с двух сторон.
[Сложноподчинённые предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html)

*Я не видел ничего — **ни того, что** находится по сторонам, **ни того, что** ждет меня внизу, ни самого себя* (коллектив авторов).
*Чтобы чувствовать цену **того, чем** вы владеете, представьте себе, что вы потеряли это* (М. Плутарх).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь два придаточных при одном главном, потому правильно.